# Select n-th line with first line condition

Tags: regex

I have subtitles file which was auto-generated for one of the Youtube videos.

Here, there are 4 speeches. Every speech has number, time, first text line and second text line.

I would like to delete every first text of line in every time spans. I need it because currently when new text comes I see the old one and the new one. In other words, old text is moving up and new comes from the bottom. I would like to see only the new one.

```
1
00:00:02,880 --> 00:00:06,550
[empty]<--to be removed
[Music]

2
00:00:06,550 --> 00:00:06,560
[Music]<--to be removed
[empty]    

3
00:00:06,560 --> 00:00:09,290
[Music]<--to be removed
my name is Maria and I'm a technical

4
00:00:09,290 --> 00:00:09,300
my name is Maria and I'm a technical<--to be removed
[empty]
```

What have I tried? I am only able to select: number line, time line and first text line. Somehow `(?=`regexp`)` doesn't work with my query. Here is my query:

```
(^\d+$\n.+$\n)
```

- `^\d+$` - starts and ends with digit elements
- `\n.+$` - select new line, select all elements till the end of the line
- `\n` - select one more line but don't select elements

Comment: *"Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."* - [regex tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^(\d+\r?\n.*?-->.*)\r?\n.+
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KwJOrh/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+\r?\n.*?-->.*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line break
  - `.*?-->.*` -  a line that has `-->` (this is to make matching safer, your `.+` can do, too, if you are sure there are no subtitle text lines that are only made up of digits)
- `\r?\n` - CRLF or LF
- `.+` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars.

Comment: Okay, what if I cannot use groups? Can I somehow use it with `(?=...).+` ?

Comment: @deadfish What is the environment? You must be able to use capturing groups.

Comment: @deadfish What *can* you use? If `$1` is not supported, `\1` should. Capturing groups are supported even in POSIX regex, your environment can't fail to support them.

Comment: @deadfish You can see that `\r?\n` is out of the group and should not be removed, thus, `\n` in the replacement should be redundant (probably, my initial `[^\r\n]` is still  a better choice for CRLF endings, `^(\d+\r?\n.*?-->[^\r\n]*)\r?\n.+`)